# How to Attach Event to HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I know you can directly do:

```
<canvas id="someCanvas" onmousedown="blah();">

<script>
function blah() {
dosomething();
}
</script>
```

How would I attach the event in code only?

I tried doing:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("someCanvas");

canvas.onmousedown = function() {
  doSomething();
}
```

But it does not work and doSomething does not get called... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/6CdrS/ Make sure the code is executed when the DOM is loaded. I.e. either attach a callback to `body.onload` or put the code at the bottom of the page (or in general: after the canvas element). Also close the canvas element properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AddEventListener, as such:

> canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",
>   function() {} );

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: Should not make a difference. AND you have to mention that it has to be `canvas.attachEvent` in IE.